# Convert Integer to Little Endian Hex String

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, long-integer, endianness

I'm trying to convert an integer to a little endian hex string.  I can get to a little endian hex long but I'm not sure how to convert to string from there.

```
int iNum = 17706; 
// convert to long little endian hex
long lNum = (long)_byteswap_ushort(iNum);
// convert to string??
```

Alternatively, is there a way to go straight from an integer to little endian hex string?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::ostringstream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::stringstream` to format strings.

Also, use `_byteswap_ulong` or large ints will not be accurate.

```
long iNum = 17706; 
// convert to long little endian hex
long lNum = (long)_byteswap_ulong(iNum);
// convert to string
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::hex << lNum;
std::string mystring = oss.str();
```

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO: if you have a new question, please search for someone who already asked it, and if you can't find one, post a _new_ question.  This question has been answered, not just for you, but for everyone who has this problem in the future.

Comment: I just looked up ushort, it can go up to 65535 which is a 16bit binary.  This is the biggest number the hardware can accept, so it is perfect.  Thanks for the warning.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO good to hear. The important part is to be wary if you're converting types that could be different sizes. I'm betting that _byteswap_ulong will do the right thing on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

For a portable solution, just mask and shift:

```
while (iNum != 0) {
    int byte = iNum & 0x0F;
    std::cout << std::hex << byte;
    iNum /= 16;
}
```